# Magento2 2.4.3 docker memory limits

Tags: php, docker, magento, memory, magento2

I've set up a docker container for the Magento2 installer.

I've also set up the db and pass all the env vars through docker-compose to the relevant services.

[link to repository here](https://github.com/richardhp/magento2-docker)

### Steps to reproduce

First set all the relevant env vars.  Then build the magento installer image:

```bash
docker-compose build magento_installer
```

I start up the database with this command:

```bash
docker-compose up magento_db -d
```

Then run the installer:

```bash
docker-compose run magento_installer
```

### The error

The output I get is this:

```bash
docker-compose run magento_installer
Creating magento2-docker_magento_installer_run ... done
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 1386]
Required extensions check...
[Progress: 2 / 1386]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...
[Progress: 3 / 1386]
Installing deployment configuration...
[Progress: 4 / 1386]
Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_AdminAnalytics':
[Progress: 5 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Store':
[Progress: 6 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeIms':
[Progress: 7 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeImsApi':
[Progress: 8 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi':
[Progress: 9 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGallery':
[Progress: 10 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockAssetApi':
[Progress: 11 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockClient':
[Progress: 12 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockClientApi':
[Progress: 13 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockImage':
[Progress: 14 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Directory':
[Progress: 15 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockImageApi':
[Progress: 16 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
[Progress: 17 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Theme':
[Progress: 18 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
[Progress: 19 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AmqpStore':
[Progress: 20 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Config':
[Progress: 21 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Backend':
[Progress: 22 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
[Progress: 23 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Eav':
[Progress: 24 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Variable':
[Progress: 25 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Search':
[Progress: 26 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Backup':
[Progress: 27 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Customer':
[Progress: 28 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
[Progress: 29 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
[Progress: 30 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
[Progress: 31 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
[Progress: 32 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Cms':
[Progress: 33 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Rule':
[Progress: 34 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Security':
[Progress: 35 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GraphQl':
[Progress: 36 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_EavGraphQl':
[Progress: 37 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_StoreGraphQl':
[Progress: 38 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
[Progress: 39 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
[Progress: 40 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
[Progress: 41 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics':
[Progress: 42 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
[Progress: 43 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
[Progress: 44 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl':
[Progress: 45 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
[Progress: 46 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
[Progress: 47 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogGraphQl':
[Progress: 48 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
[Progress: 49 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Quote':
[Progress: 50 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
[Progress: 51 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl':
[Progress: 52 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryUi':
[Progress: 53 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CmsGraphQl':
[Progress: 54 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics':
[Progress: 55 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
[Progress: 56 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl':
[Progress: 57 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CompareListGraphQl':
[Progress: 58 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin':
[Progress: 59 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_User':
[Progress: 60 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Payment':
[Progress: 61 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Sales':
[Progress: 62 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_QuoteGraphQl':
[Progress: 63 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
[Progress: 64 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Contact':
[Progress: 65 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
[Progress: 66 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Cron':
[Progress: 67 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Csp':
[Progress: 68 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Widget':
[Progress: 69 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Robots':
[Progress: 70 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Integration':
[Progress: 71 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
[Progress: 72 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CustomerGraphQl':
[Progress: 73 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
[Progress: 74 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
[Progress: 75 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Developer':
[Progress: 76 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
[Progress: 77 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
[Progress: 78 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl':
[Progress: 79 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl':
[Progress: 80 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl':
[Progress: 81 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
[Progress: 82 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl':
[Progress: 83 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_BundleGraphQl':
[Progress: 84 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdvancedSearch':
[Progress: 85 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch':
[Progress: 86 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch6':
[Progress: 87 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Email':
[Progress: 88 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
[Progress: 89 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
[Progress: 90 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
[Progress: 91 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GiftMessageGraphQl':
[Progress: 92 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
[Progress: 93 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
[Progress: 94 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Ui':
[Progress: 95 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GoogleShoppingAds':
[Progress: 96 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl':
[Progress: 97 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
[Progress: 98 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
[Progress: 99 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
[Progress: 100 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory':
[Progress: 101 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl':
[Progress: 102 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
[Progress: 103 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
[Progress: 104 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
[Progress: 105 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Analytics':
[Progress: 106 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Inventory':
[Progress: 107 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryAdminUi':
[Progress: 108 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout':
[Progress: 109 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryApi':
[Progress: 110 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport':
[Progress: 111 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct':
[Progress: 112 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi':
[Progress: 113 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer':
[Progress: 114 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalog':
[Progress: 115 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySales':
[Progress: 116 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi':
[Progress: 117 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi':
[Progress: 118 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi':
[Progress: 119 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch':
[Progress: 120 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct':
[Progress: 121 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct':
[Progress: 122 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
[Progress: 123 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl':
[Progress: 124 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct':
[Progress: 125 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer':
[Progress: 126 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfiguration':
[Progress: 127 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi':
[Progress: 128 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection':
[Progress: 129 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi':
[Progress: 130 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi':
[Progress: 131 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch':
[Progress: 132 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi':
[Progress: 133 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryIndexer':
[Progress: 134 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesApi':
[Progress: 135 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct':
[Progress: 136 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi':
[Progress: 137 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer':
[Progress: 138 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryImportExport':
[Progress: 139 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi':
[Progress: 140 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi':
[Progress: 141 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi':
[Progress: 142 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickup':
[Progress: 143 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl':
[Progress: 144 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
[Progress: 145 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi':
[Progress: 146 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl':
[Progress: 147 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales':
[Progress: 148 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi':
[Progress: 149 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote':
[Progress: 150 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping':
[Progress: 151 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi':
[Progress: 152 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
[Progress: 153 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
[Progress: 154 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryCache':
[Progress: 155 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification':
[Progress: 156 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Reports':
[Progress: 157 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi':
[Progress: 158 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi':
[Progress: 159 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryProductAlert':
[Progress: 160 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl':
[Progress: 161 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryRequisitionList':
[Progress: 162 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservations':
[Progress: 163 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationCli':
[Progress: 164 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi':
[Progress: 165 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStock':
[Progress: 166 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi':
[Progress: 167 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl':
[Progress: 168 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi':
[Progress: 169 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator':
[Progress: 170 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryShipping':
[Progress: 171 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi':
[Progress: 172 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi':
[Progress: 173 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelection':
[Progress: 174 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend':
[Progress: 175 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi':
[Progress: 176 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser':
[Progress: 177 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryWishlist':
[Progress: 178 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_JwtFrameworkAdapter':
[Progress: 179 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
[Progress: 180 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomer':
[Progress: 181 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi':
[Progress: 182 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi':
[Progress: 183 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance':
[Progress: 184 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi':
[Progress: 185 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl':
[Progress: 186 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog':
[Progress: 187 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache':
[Progress: 188 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote':
[Progress: 189 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales':
[Progress: 190 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
[Progress: 191 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContent':
[Progress: 192 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentApi':
[Progress: 193 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentCatalog':
[Progress: 194 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentCms':
[Progress: 195 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentSynchronization':
[Progress: 196 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationApi':
[Progress: 197 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCatalog':
[Progress: 198 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCms':
[Progress: 199 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockAsset':
[Progress: 200 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryApi':
[Progress: 201 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalog':
[Progress: 202 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogIntegration':
[Progress: 203 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogUi':
[Progress: 204 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryCmsUi':
[Progress: 205 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryIntegration':
[Progress: 206 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryMetadata':
[Progress: 207 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryMetadataApi':
[Progress: 208 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryRenditions':
[Progress: 209 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryRenditionsApi':
[Progress: 210 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronization':
[Progress: 211 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationApi':
[Progress: 212 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationMetadata':
[Progress: 213 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockImageAdminUi':
[Progress: 214 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGalleryUiApi':
[Progress: 215 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
[Progress: 216 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MessageQueue':
[Progress: 217 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
[Progress: 218 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct':
[Progress: 219 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct':
[Progress: 220 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping':
[Progress: 221 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MysqlMq':
[Progress: 222 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
[Progress: 223 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
[Progress: 224 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_NewsletterGraphQl':
[Progress: 225 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
[Progress: 226 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
[Progress: 227 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
[Progress: 228 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PageBuilder':
[Progress: 229 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics':
[Progress: 230 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GraphQlCache':
[Progress: 231 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CardinalCommerce':
[Progress: 232 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Vault':
[Progress: 233 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
[Progress: 234 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PaypalGraphQl':
[Progress: 235 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
[Progress: 236 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
[Progress: 237 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
[Progress: 238 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
[Progress: 239 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
[Progress: 240 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_QuoteBundleOptions':
[Progress: 241 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_QuoteConfigurableOptions':
[Progress: 242 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_QuoteDownloadableLinks':
[Progress: 243 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi':
[Progress: 244 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaAdminUi':
[Progress: 245 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaCheckout':
[Progress: 246 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaContact':
[Progress: 247 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaCustomer':
[Progress: 248 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi':
[Progress: 249 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaMigration':
[Progress: 250 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaNewsletter':
[Progress: 251 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal':
[Progress: 252 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaReview':
[Progress: 253 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaSendFriend':
[Progress: 254 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaStorePickup':
[Progress: 255 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaUi':
[Progress: 256 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaUser':
[Progress: 257 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaValidation':
[Progress: 258 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaValidationApi':
[Progress: 259 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Checkbox':
[Progress: 260 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Invisible':
[Progress: 261 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion3Invisible':
[Progress: 262 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiApi':
[Progress: 263 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl':
[Progress: 264 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiRest':
[Progress: 265 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi':
[Progress: 266 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl':
[Progress: 267 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
[Progress: 268 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_RemoteStorage':
[Progress: 269 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi':
[Progress: 270 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
[Progress: 271 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Review':
[Progress: 272 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
[Progress: 273 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ReviewGraphQl':
[Progress: 274 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AwsS3':
[Progress: 275 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Rss':
[Progress: 276 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PageBuilderAdminAnalytics':
[Progress: 277 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
[Progress: 278 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
[Progress: 279 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SalesGraphQl':
[Progress: 280 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
[Progress: 281 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
[Progress: 282 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
[Progress: 283 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
[Progress: 284 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch7':
[Progress: 285 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
[Progress: 286 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Securitytxt':
[Progress: 287 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
[Progress: 288 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl':
[Progress: 289 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi':
[Progress: 290 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AwsS3PageBuilder':
[Progress: 291 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryGraphQl':
[Progress: 292 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl':
[Progress: 293 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
[Progress: 294 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapi':
[Progress: 295 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync':
[Progress: 296 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
[Progress: 297 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl':
[Progress: 298 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
[Progress: 299 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Tax':
[Progress: 300 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_TaxGraphQl':
[Progress: 301 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
[Progress: 302 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AsynchronousOperations':
[Progress: 303 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_ThemeGraphQl':
[Progress: 304 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Translation':
[Progress: 305 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_TwoFactorAuth':
[Progress: 306 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
[Progress: 307 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Ups':
[Progress: 308 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
[Progress: 309 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl':
[Progress: 310 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
[Progress: 311 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Usps':
[Progress: 312 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi':
[Progress: 313 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_PaypalCaptcha':
[Progress: 314 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_VaultGraphQl':
[Progress: 315 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Version':
[Progress: 316 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension':
[Progress: 317 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_WebapiAsync':
[Progress: 318 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
[Progress: 319 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Weee':
[Progress: 320 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_WeeeGraphQl':
[Progress: 321 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
[Progress: 322 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
[Progress: 323 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
[Progress: 324 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_WishlistGraphQl':
[Progress: 325 / 1386]
Module 'Amazon_Core':
[Progress: 326 / 1386]
Module 'Amazon_Login':
[Progress: 327 / 1386]
Module 'Amazon_Payment':
[Progress: 328 / 1386]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
[Progress: 329 / 1386]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Chat':
[Progress: 330 / 1386]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_ChatGraphQl':
[Progress: 331 / 1386]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_EmailGraphQl':
[Progress: 332 / 1386]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Sms':
[Progress: 333 / 1386]
Module 'Klarna_Core':
[Progress: 334 / 1386]
Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
[Progress: 335 / 1386]
Module 'Klarna_Kp':
[Progress: 336 / 1386]
Module 'Klarna_Onsitemessaging':
[Progress: 337 / 1386]
Module 'Klarna_KpGraphQl':
[Progress: 338 / 1386]
Module 'PayPal_Braintree':
[Progress: 339 / 1386]
Module 'PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl':
[Progress: 340 / 1386]
Module 'Temando_ShippingRemover':
[Progress: 341 / 1386]
Module 'Vertex_Tax':
[Progress: 342 / 1386]
Module 'Vertex_AddressValidationApi':
[Progress: 343 / 1386]
Module 'Vertex_RequestLoggingApi':
[Progress: 344 / 1386]
Module 'Vertex_RequestLogging':
[Progress: 345 / 1386]
Module 'Vertex_AddressValidation':
[Progress: 346 / 1386]
Module 'Yotpo_Yotpo':
[Progress: 347 / 1386]
Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_AdminAnalytics':
[Progress: 348 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Store':
[Progress: 349 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeIms':
[Progress: 350 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeImsApi':
[Progress: 351 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi':
[Progress: 352 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_MediaGallery':
[Progress: 353 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockAssetApi':
[Progress: 354 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockClient':
[Progress: 355 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockClientApi':
[Progress: 356 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockImage':
[Progress: 357 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Directory':
[Progress: 358 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdobeStockImageApi':
[Progress: 359 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
[Progress: 360 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Theme':
[Progress: 361 / 1386]
Module 'Magento_Amqp':

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/Website/Interceptor.php on line 533

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor does not exist in /magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 /magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(28): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Store\\M...')
#1 /magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Store\\M...')
#2 /magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Store\\M...')
#3 /magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array)
#4 /magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/WebsiteFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Store\\...', Array)
#5 /magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository. in /magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 28
ERROR: 255
```

Doesn't seem to matter what I set the memory limit to, I always get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did manage to solve this issue recently.

The

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
```

setting in docker-compose.yml did absolutely nothing.

What was effective however, was editing the memory_limit option in the php.ini file inside the docker container did actually make a difference.

So I just added some code to the Dockerfile to set that value higher and the code ran without running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache server you can increase the memory limit in the `docker-compose.yml` file define the environment and set `MEMORY_LIMIT: 1000000M`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
phpmyadmin: 
        ports:
        - "3030:80" 
        environment:
            MEMORY_LIMIT: 1000000M
```

after that run the command `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

I increased the memory limit to 256M and it worked for me.

In the docker file /php_ini/conf.d/php.ini find and update as required

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Make sure your docker-compose.yml is loading that folder for php

```
volumes:
        - ./php_ini:/usr/local/etc/php
```